# How to display Mat image on android emulator? Using NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I would like to display a Mat image on the android emulator. I am passing an assetManager from `java` to `c++` and loading an image as an asset. I then perform an AAsset_read, and save the image data into a char* buffer, and convert to Mat using `cv::imdecode`.
From here, how do I go about adding the Mat image to the emulator?

In the default `stringFromJNI` method, they seem to use re`turn->envNewStringUTF(hello.c_str());` which displays the text:

```
Java_com_example_user_project_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */) {

std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
```

So how do I go about doing this with a Mat image?

edit: here is my c++ code :

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL     Java_com_example_user_activity_MainActivity_generateAssets(JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz,jobject assetManager) {

AAsset* img;

AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(mgr, "");
const char* filename;
while ((filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir)) != NULL) {
    AAsset *asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, filename, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);

    if(strcmp(filename, "hi.jpg")==0 ) {
        img = asset;
    }
}
long sizeOfImg = AAsset_getLength(img);
char* buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*sizeOfImg);
AAsset_read(img, buffer, sizeOfImg);


std::vector<char> data(buffer, buffer + sizeOfImg);

cv::Mat h = cv::imdecode(data, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

jintArray resultImage = env->NewIntArray(h.total());
jint *_data = new jint[h.total()];
for (int i = 0; i < h.total(); i++) {
    char b = h.data[4 * i];
    char g = h.data[4 * i + 1];
    char r = h.data[4 * i + 2];
    char a = 255;
    _data[i] = (((jint) a << 24) & 0xFF000000) + (((jint) r << 16) & 0x00FF0000) +
               (((jint) g << 8) & 0x0000FF00) + ((jint) b & 0x000000FF);
}
env->SetIntArrayRegion(resultImage, 0, h.total(), _data);
delete[]_data;
return resultImage;

}
```

And the java code:

```
    assetManager = getAssets();
    resultImage = generateAssets(assetManager);

    Bitmap imageinjava = Bitmap.createBitmap(resultImage, 100,100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    ImageView tv1;
    tv1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    tv1.setImageBitmap(imageinjava);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adding the Mat image to the emulator"?

Comment: Just display it on the screen. Like how the code displays "hello from c++" i'd like to display the image

Comment: If you are not using java opencv API - best goal is to create Bitmap from your image. You can return jintArray with RGBA data of your Mat object and than create Bitmap by calling Bitmap.createBitmap

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this- I am using OpenCV and need it to be a Mat object because I want to do further processing with the Mat object later on. This is just a helloworld stage.

Comment: If you want to pass native objects between java and c++ than you can return pointer to your Mat object. It won't be possible to use your native object in java though (without using opencv java api)

Comment: My goal is to do all of the opencv Mat image processing in c++ and pass the final image back to java to display. Will I still need to use opencv java api?

Comment: No, if you will not use your native Mat object after processing - just convert it to Bitmap. Of course there are native functions to display images on SurfaceView or GLSurfaceView (like ANativeWindow API), but if your goal is not very high performance - i would suggest to use Bitmap

Comment: In order to show Bitmap you can use ImageView or any other view which is capable of showing Bitmaps

Comment: Also if you are looking for a fast way to debug your results - you can also just write your image to storage using imwrite (make sure you add permission to write to external storage before doing that)

Comment: The fastest way to display RGB image from native code is with OpenGL glTexSubImage2D function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert your native Mat image you can do that:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL  Java_com_example_user_activity_MainActivity_generateAssets(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject assetManager) {
AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
AAsset *img = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "hi.jpg", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);

long sizeOfImg = AAsset_getLength(img);
char* buffer = (char*)AAsset_getBuffer(img);

std::vector<char> data(buffer, buffer + sizeOfImg);

cv::Mat h = cv::imdecode(data, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

jintArray resultImage = env->NewIntArray(h.total());
jint *_data = new jint[h.total()];
for (int i = 0; i < h.total(); i++) {
    char b = h.data[h.channels() * i];
    char g = h.data[h.channels() * i + 1];
    char r = h.data[h.channels() * i + 2];
    char a = 255;
    _data[i] = (((jint) a << 24) & 0xFF000000) + (((jint) r << 16) & 0x00FF0000) +
               (((jint) g << 8) & 0x0000FF00) + ((jint) b & 0x000000FF);
}
env->SetIntArrayRegion(resultImage, 0, h.total(), _data);
delete[]_data;
return resultImage;
```

}

And in your java code smth like that

```
    int[] result = generateAssets(getAssets());
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(result, yourimagewidth, yourimageheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

If you want to pass native Mat object between c++ and java - return pointer to your Mat and pass it later into native function;

```
Mat *mat = new Mat(100, 100);
return (jlong) mat;
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this but it's not working and I don't really understand what's going on. ResultImage is retuning null. Please can you explain what you've done? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think you were over complicating reading from assets. That code will read file hi.jpg from root asset folder ("assets/hi.jpg") and will return jintArray to java

Comment: Thank you very much it works! However I'm still not sure what you've done inside the for loop beginning: for (int i = 0; i < h.total(); i++) {... Please can you explain what you've done here?

Comment: @Ber12345 Sure. Since Bitmap constructor requires RGBA data stored into integer (4 bytes) i just iterate over whole image (h.total() = h.size().width * h.size().height) and put red green and blue values of each pixel into integer with alpha (transparency) set to 255 which means no transparency. Since i don't know if image is 4 or 3 channels - i use h.channels() to correctly get each pixel's value. If something still doesn't make much sense for you - please tell me

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. One more thing, how do I find my image height and width on the java side?

Comment: You can return them from jni, for example as last to values of your jintArray resultImage or pass Integer objects into your native function as parameters

Comment: Thank you, i've managed to figure out almost everything from this. Is there any chance you know how to print out the contents of a Mat to the android studio console in NDK? I can use the debugger, however I'm not sure where to look to find the data inside the Mat.

Comment: __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "ADD TAG NAME", "%d %d", h.rows, h.cols); I don't think printing actual colors is useful cause its a bunch of values 0-255, but if u want - u can access h.data as i did in my answer